# ngOnInit method is not called

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngoninit

When I navigate to my component after the first time, with `router.navigate`, the `ngOnInit` method of the component is not called.

Therefore, the previous data I fetched from API is still there. I need to reset all the variables when I navigate away from the page, so the next time the component is re-built from scratch again.

How can I achieve it?

I tried to google for solutions, I tried to change some code, I unsubscribed inside `ngOnDestroy` but nothing changed.

Comment: Without a code sample this is almost impossible to debug.

Comment: If the URL parameters change, you can inject `ActivatedRoute` and subscribe to `paramMap` or `queryParamMap`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
this.router.navigate(['your link'])
```